# Using Refs To Style A Div Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Good day,

I'm new to react JS and I want to get a div element using refs and style it. It gives an error(can't read the property style of undefined).

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'

function Menubar() {
  const [show, setshow] = useState(false)
  const clickref = useRef()
  const openMenu = () => {
    if (show === false) {
      clickref.current.style.display = "block";
      setshow(true);
    }
    clickref.current.style.display = "none";
    setshow(false);
  }
  return (
    <div className="menu">
      <div className="menuBar">
        <div className="navBar ">
          <img src={Drop} alt="DrpBtn" className="drpBtn" onClick={openMenu()} />
          <ul className="navCon" ref={clickref}>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/menu">Menu</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/news">News</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/contact">Contact Us</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/patner">Patner</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Menubar
```

Comment: Why would you use a ref here? You're already keeping track of the state (`show`). With this you could simply do `<ul className="navCon" style={{display: show ? 'block' : 'none'}}>`.

Comment: okay let me try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're new to react I'd say you're misusing refs here. Use the state value you already have to do the logic, e.g.:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Menubar() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    // toggle the current state
    setShow(current => !current);
  };

  return (
    <div className="menu">
      <div className="menuBar">
        <div className="navBar ">
          <button onClick={toggleMenu}>toggle</button>

          {/*use show to handle the styling*/}
          <ul className="navCon" style={{display: show ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/menu">Menu</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/news">News</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/contact">Contact Us</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/patner">Patner</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Menubar;
```

Comment: cool it worked, so when is a more suitable situation to use refs

Comment: by the way Thank you very much, I really appreciate

Comment: That's a big topic. But in general you want `useState/useReducer` for state handling and `useRef` when interacting with the DOM outside of react mechanisms, special handling of the render cycle (among other use cases). Also check the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref and generally https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Change `onClick={openMenu()}` to `onClick={openMenu}`

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Fixing `onClick={openMenu}` is not enought, your display style is always `none`, to fix it add an else expression:

```
const openMenu = () => {
  if (show === false) {
    clickref.current.style.display = "block";
    setshow(true);
  } else {
    clickref.current.style.display = "none";
    setshow(false);
  }
};

// same logic
const openMenu = () => {
  clickref.current.style.display = show ? "block" : "none";
  setshow((prev) => !prev);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate